# Multi layer interactivity not working with carto.js

Tags: carto, html, carto-js

I've two sublayers with interaction set as `true` and the proper columns added in the interactivity method. The `featureClick` listener is attached to the layer. On the one hand, popups are working on both sublayers independently when they are alone. But when both sublayers are present only the top-sublayer is triggering the `featureClick` event. How can I launch both popups from the two sublayers?

Comment: Can you try having an empty sublayer-0 and putting your data layers into 1 and 2. I've had this same issue before where the cartojs is expecting the actual map layer in the zero index, and not your data.

Comment: @jags can you suggest how to set an empty layer ?

Answer (score 1):

As Ramiroaznar, you can use the brand new CARTO.js v4 library to get interactivity in two layers and get your events in both of them.

You can check this gist. If you click on a city, you'll see in the console the country from one layer and the city from the other one.

https://bl.ocks.org/ivanmalagon/f35d350606bbe460cd9ae984469a6cf0

If you can afford moving to CARTO.js, it's worth a try.

Comment: I don't see anything clickable (no cities). I do see countries, but nothing happens upon click. Nothing is written to the console log, except for the following:
 
bl.ocks.org/:1 Uncaught (in promise) 
Error {message: "Unauthorized", origin: "windshaft", type: "auth", errorCode: "windshaft:auth:unknown-error", name: "CartoError", …}
errorCode: "windshaft:auth:unknown-error"
message: "Unauthorized"
name: "CartoError"
origin: "windshaft"
originalError: i {_error: {…}, origin: "windshaft", type: "auth", subtype: "api-key-not-found", message: "Unauthorized", …}
stack: "Error↵    at new ...

Answer (score 0):

That's the expected behavior. Following the `Detect feature flick` and `Add more layers` example [from CARTO.js v4 documentation](https://carto.com/documentation/cartojs/), you can create an example [similar to this one](https://bl.ocks.org/ramiroaznar/cd367e4fe8dd11d8d87d9d20cfffca08):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Feature click + 2 layers | CARTO.js v4</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,600,700|Open+Sans:300,400,600" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Include Leaflet -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Include CARTO.js -->
    <script src="https://cartodb-libs.global.ssl.fastly.net/carto.js/v4.0.0-beta.20/carto.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      body, *{ margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #map {
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      const map = L.map('map').setView([30, 0], 3);

      L.tileLayer('https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/rastertiles/voyager_nolabels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 18
      }).addTo(map);

      const client = new carto.Client({
        apiKey: 'YOUR_API_KEY',
        username: 'ramirocartodb'
      });

      const citySource = new carto.source.Dataset(`
        ne_10m_populated_places_simple
      `);
      const cityStyle = new carto.style.CartoCSS(`
        #layer {
          marker-width: 7;
          marker-fill: #EE4D5A;
          marker-line-color: #FFFFFF;
        }
      `);
      const cityLayer = new carto.layer.Layer(citySource, cityStyle, {
        featureClickColumns: ['name', 'pop_max']
      });

      const worldSource = new carto.source.Dataset(`
        world_borders
      `);
      const worldStyle = new carto.style.CartoCSS(`
        #layer {
          polygon-fill: #826DBA;
          polygon-opacity: 0.8;
          ::outline {
            line-width: 1;
            line-color: #FFFFFF;
            line-opacity: 0.8;
          }
        }
      `);
      const worldLayer = new carto.layer.Layer(worldSource, worldStyle, {
        featureClickColumns: ['name', 'pop2005']
      });

      client.addLayers([worldLayer, cityLayer]);
      client.getLeafletLayer().addTo(map);

      const cityPopup = L.popup({ closeButton: false });
      cityLayer.on('featureClicked', featureEvent => {
        cityPopup.setLatLng(featureEvent.latLng);
        let city = featureEvent.data.name;
        let pop_max = featureEvent.data.pop_max;
        cityPopup.setContent(`
          <h2>${city}</h2>
          <h3>${pop_max} inhab.</h3>
          `);
        cityPopup.openOn(map);
      });

      const worldPopup = L.popup({ closeButton: false });
      worldLayer.on('featureClicked', featureEvent => {
        worldPopup.setLatLng(featureEvent.latLng);
        let country = featureEvent.data.name;
        let pop2005 = featureEvent.data.pop2005;
        worldPopup.setContent(`
          <h2>${country}</h2>
          <h3>${pop2005} inhab.</h3>
          `);
        worldPopup.openOn(map);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: featureClick]

**UPDATE**: check @Ivan Malagon to see how it can be done. :-)